# How to make random value function return different value each time

Tags: c, random, srand

I've been trying to write a small C function for generating random values. The problem is that it returns same value each time the function is called in for loop. I understand the problem is that srand is seeded with NULL. What I want to know is how to correct it, so that on each iteration of for loop the function returns a different value. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int randInt(int,int);

void main(){

    int min=100, max=200,i=0;

    for(i;i<11;i++){ printf("%d \n",randInt(min,max));  }

}


int randInt(int a,int b){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randValue;
    randValue=1+(int)rand()%(b-a+1);
    return randValue;

}
```

Please let me know if you have a solution or can post some reference to a solution. Thank you in advance !

Edit : Encountered Problem #2, after having replaced srand(time(NULL)) into main, every  iteration now generates numbers bellow my range, i.e. originally i wanted numbers between 100 and 200, but it also included numbers between 0 and 100. This was solved with `randValue=a+(int)rand()%(b-a+1);` as suggested in the comments

Comment: Don't call `srand` inside the random function.

Comment: To expand on Retired Ninja's comment. srand is used for (one time)initialization, then rand is used to retrieve the value.

Comment: Thank you, Ninja, it worked ! Now, just one more small question - I'm trying to generate numbers from 100 to 200, however the function generated values bellow 100. How do i fix that?

Comment: Bung `srand(time(NULL));` just after main

Comment: @Xieerqi That's because `rand()%(101);` You can't get higher nubmer than 100

Comment: Note: Typically the `srand(time(NULL));` in `main()` trick does not work to "make random value function return different value each time" if the code is executed twice in the same second.  An alternative is to pull the `seed` in `srand(seed)` value from a file and increment it each program run.  Many approaches exist to solve this problem.

Comment: @jpw Never quite comfortable using another language's (C++) answer as a duplicate of this C problem.  Certainly the languages have _similarity_ as do the answers.  Your duplicate answers talks about using `srand(time(0));` and `srand(time(nullptr))` whereas the typical C solution is `srand(time(NULL))`.  Recommend trying to find same language duplicates for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Put `srand(time(NULL));` in `main` just after the `{`

To generate random numbers in the range 100-200,instead of adding 1,add 100 or `a` to

```
randValue=(int)rand()%(b-a+1);
```

So that it looks like:

```
randValue=(int)rand()%(b-a+1)+100;
```

Comment: this will not solve his second problem

Comment: What is his Second Problem? There is nothing more in the question

Comment: you should really read comments under the question

Comment: He should have mentioned that in his question .....

Comment: @CoolGuy My second problem was that the original function generated values out of the range i wanted (between 100 and 200). It's solved now with randValue=a+(int)rand()%(b-a+1);

Comment: @CoolGuy Well, I've mentioned that in the comments just after the first problem was solved. Sorry, I'm still noobing around here. I'll keep in mind to edit the original question in future

Comment: @Xieerqi , You can still edit your question to add that too!

Answer (score 1):

I am using `min` and `max` insead of `a` and `b`. It is better for future readers of your code

1. You should use `srand(time(NULL))` only once at initialization e.g in your `main()`
2. You probably wanted `min + rand() % (max - min + 1)` instead of `rand()%(b-a+1)`

Comment: -1 You cannot Use `min` or `max` in the `randInt` function as they are local variables

Comment: @CoolGuy ups read carefully i **did** mention that

Answer (score 1):

This will print random value each time between 100-200:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int randInt(int a,int b)
{
    int randValue;
    randValue = (rand() % (b-a+1)) + a;
    return randValue;
}

int main(void) {
    int r=0, i = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    do 
    {
        r = randInt(100,200);
        printf("%d\n",r);
        i++;
    }while(i < 11);
    puts("Done!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: removed my previous comment +1